# How can I find android ndk 1.5 r1 installation file?

Tags: android, installation, android-ndk

I cannot find the old Android ndk 1.5 r1 installation file anywhere on the web (right now its r4b)? I think google dropped it becuase it shouldnt be needed anymore. Does anyone know where I can find it?

/Br Johannes

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed anymore.
The newer versions include everything the old versions had.